# Embedding Matrix for GloVe Dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, lstm, stanford-nlp

I am new to Sentiment Analysis using LSTM and GloVe Embeddings.

During my code, I got an error says that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JAMES~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16128/3567447988.py in <module>
      7   embedding_vector = word_to_vec_map.get(word)
      8   if not embedding_vector is None:
----> 9     emb_matrix[index, :] = embedding_vector

IndexError: index 2684 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2684
```

I try search up for solution but still this error occur. This is my code:

```
vocab_len = len(words_to_index)
embed_vector_len = word_to_vec_map['speed'].shape[0]

emb_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len, embed_vector_len))

for word, index in words_to_index.items():
  embedding_vector = word_to_vec_map.get(word)
  if not embedding_vector is None:
    emb_matrix[index, :] = embedding_vector
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What does `words_to_index` look like? Looks like your max `index` exceeds the vocabulary length.

Comment: can you try 'emb_matrix[index-1, :] = embedding_vector' ?